# Screen flicker after booting Windows

Tags: windows-10

## Problem

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I boot Windows, when I reach the login screen, my display starts flickering/flashing. (Basically it turns entirely grey or black about once or twice per second.) It also seems to freeze my PC temporarily; while the screen is grey I cannot move the mouse cursor or otherwise interact with Windows. I'm forced to restart my PC and try again. Usually I get lucky after 3-4 restart attempts. When Windows boots into the Advanced Startup Options menu and I select "Continue" (which is Microsoft speak for "reboot"), it almost always boots without the flickering and I'm able to use my PC.

To clarify: The flickering **only** happens immediately after booting, at the login screen. If it doesn't occur then, it won't occur later either and I'm safe until I reboot. I can even log out and back in without any risk.

I **think** the problem is related to my graphics driver (AMD), because it (almost) never occurs if I uninstall all AMD software. However, the problem still exists if I install an older version of the graphics driver (one that used to work before this issue appeared), so I'm not 100% sure.

## Summary and additional details

- Flickering either occurs at the login screen or doesn't occur at all
- Sometimes the flickering starts automatically, other times it begins when I interact with the login screen (by clicking or pressing enter)
- Flickering almost never occurs when booting from Advanced Startup Options menu
- <s>Flickering hasn't occured in Safe Mode so far</s> Flickering can occur even in Safe Mode.
- Not sure if relevant, but often after a successful boot, some of the icons in my task bar notification area do not render
- Flickering is limited to Windows; nonexistant on linux (just in case anyone thought it was a hardware problem)
- In order to test if the flickering exists, I have often rebooted my PC without doing anything - boot, login, reboot, login, reboot. This usually let me boot without any problems, which made it difficult to test if a "fix" worked or not. I'm starting to think that the flickering only occurs if I've actually used the PC before rebooting - maybe I have to start a certain program for it to occur?

## Attempted solutions

- Disabled "AMD External Events Utility" service
- Disabled "Windows Error Reporting Service" and "Problem Reports and Solutions Control Panel Support" services
- Disabled *all* non-windows services
- Reinstalled graphics driver
- Installed older graphics driver
- Disabled graphics card (through device manager -> right click -> disable device)
- Reinstalled Windows (multiple times, but the issue existed every single time)
- Turned on automatic login to bypass the login screen. PC then boots into a black screen instead.

## Question

What can I do to fix or further diagnose this problem?

Comment: You are using desktop or laptop.

Comment: @vembutech It's a desktop PC.

Comment: Have you tried without graphics card?

Comment: If you can check this graphics card with another PC.

Comment: I haven't physically removed the graphics card from the PC, but I have now disabled the card with Windows Device Manager. I'll report any updates as soon as something happens. Also, I have just now experienced the flickering in safe mode...

Comment: Try removing and check with another PC so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: (Very late) update: I didn't get to try the graphics card in a different PC, so I still don't know if it's perhaps a hardware problem. I've tried to narrow down the cause of the flickering (like I said in the question, it doesn't occur if I reboot immediately after a successful boot; only after I've used the PC for a few hours), but it's incredibly time consuming and I haven't been able to figure anything out.

Comment: Are you're desktop part of a domain? I had flickering issues with group policy update that causes flickering, and on startup group policies are processed (https://serverfault.com/q/842750/391060). You mentioned booting in to black screen, I had similar issues with antivirus; try to disable it if you have one.

Comment: @chloesoe I don't think it's part of a domain, no. About the antivirus: The flickering still occurs without any antivirus, with the exception of Windows' builtin virus protection, which, I think, can't be turned off.

Comment: I have now successfully worked around the problem by downgrading to Windows 7. I still have no idea what was causing the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an issue of bios of motherboard or gpu 
I will suggest you to reflash your vbios and update you motherboard bios and make sure you have installed chipset and pci drivers 
You can install those drivers in device manager by simply updating every driver there that would help you make sure it is not a driver issue 
If nothing works then you must flash your both bios again

Comment: Needs converted to a comment, tag a mod with the flag and request.