# What is different about Window's boot process when booting from the Advanced Startup menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I have [a very persistent problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1210396/screen-flicker-after-booting-windows) (tl;dr: Screen flickers after booting) that usually doesn't occur after the PC is rebooted from the [Advanced Startup Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/650x452ximage151.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.2DiifhdBQu.png). (To be clear, I'm not changing any boot settings - when Windows asks me if I want to enter the Startup menu, I immediately press the "get me out here, just reboot" button.)

As such, I'm wondering how the boot process is different after having entered the Advanced Startup Menu? Does Windows start up with fewer background services? Does it temporarily ignore the "fast boot" setting and perform a cold boot? What's different that could make graphics problems disappear?

Comment: run up msconfig and have a look at your boot options, it's probably the 'base video' option that's set/not set when using advanced.

Comment: @spikey_richie So far (I've only rebooted once) that doesn't seem to be it. It didn't change anything (other than my resolution). I've been forced to reinstall my graphics driver today because it completely broke down, but I'll test it more extensively once I know if the same thing happens with the newly installed driver.